# Do SLR(1) parsers have lookahead?

Tags: context-free, terminology, parsers

The SLR(1) parses AFAIK does not have any lookahead with it then why do we write it as SLR(1) and not as SLR(0). The thing about parsers which I read online taught me that if it's LR(K) then K represent the number of lookahead symbols. Thereby it's not making much sense to me.

Kindly help me here

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please change your title to reflect your actual question. Make it focused.

Comment: Is it fine now?

Comment: they do have lookaheads. Does that answer your question? Edit: Also, read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_LR_parser for a start.